# Lambda expression not returning value

Tags: python, lambda, expression

I don't understand why does this code return repr of object instead of value 20.

```
>>> a = 10
>>> lambda a: a*2
```

This is what is returned to standard output:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x02D93780>
```

Comment: You need to _call_ the function to get its return value.

Comment: `lambda` is an operator and has to be used with functions such as `map`

Comment: @grshankar Or just called like any other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function and pass it the parameter.

```
a = 10
(lambda a: a*2)(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# declaring the lambda
my_lambda_function = lambda a: a*2

# calling the lambda
my_lambda_function(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your function object to some variable to use it in future. Lambda expression creates function object (like def statement), and you need to **call** it to retrieve result

```
>>> a = 10
>>> myfunc = lambda a: a*2
>>> myfunc(11) #22
22
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you created a function, so it printed the function to the console. When you created the function it printed the literal memory location of the function. You will have to store the function in a variable and print it to get the output, vs. the memory location and type of function. Here is an example:

```
>>> a = 10

>>> lambda a: a *2

<function <lambda> at 0x033E7978>
>>> print(a)

10
```